# Converting several array into separate hashes within one array

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge, hash

I need to use the following data to construct an array of hashes. The first element in the array should be:

```
 {
   salutation: 'Mr.'
   first_name: 'John',
   last_name: 'Dillinger',
   address: '33 Foolish Lane, Boston MA 02210'
 }
```

The given data is below. I am really struggling to figure out how to do this. Some help would be greatly appreciated as I am currently at wits end!!!

```
 salutations = [
   'Mr.',
   'Mrs.',
   'Mr.',
   'Dr.',
   'Ms.'
 ]

 first_names = [
   'John',
   'Jane',
   'Sam',
   'Louise',
   'Kyle'
 ]

 last_names = [
   'Dillinger',
   'Cook',
   'Livingston',
   'Levinger',
   'Merlotte'
 ]

 addresses = [
   '33 Foolish Lane, Boston MA 02210',
   '45 Cottage Way, Dartmouth, MA 02342',
   "54 Sally's Court, Bridgewater, MA 02324",
   '4534 Broadway, Boston, MA 02110',
   '4231 Cynthia Drive, Raynham, MA 02767'
 ]
```

The only solution i was able to come up with doesn't work. Any idea why???

```
array_of_hashes = []
array_index = 0

 def array_to_hash (salutations, first_names, last_names, addresses)
   while array_index <= 5
     hash = {}
     hash[salutation] = salutations(array_index)
     hash[first_name] = first_names(array_index)
     hash[last_name] = last_names(array_index)
     hash[address] = addresses(array_index)
     array_of_hashes << hash
     array_index += 1
  end
end

array_to_hash(salutations,first_names,last_names,addresses)
```

EDIT - With help from you guys I was able to get my solution to work:

```
 def array_to_hash (salutations, first_names, last_names, addresses)
   array_of_hashes = []
   array_index = 0
   while array_index <= 4
     hash = {}
     hash[:salutation] = salutations[array_index]
     hash[:first_name] = first_names[array_index]
     hash[:last_name] = last_names[array_index]
     hash[:address] = addresses[array_index]
     array_of_hashes << hash
     array_index += 1
   end
   puts array_of_hashes
 end

 array_to_hash(salutations,first_names,last_names,addresses)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[salutations, first_names, last_names, addresses].transpose
.map{|a| Hash[%i[salutation first_name last_name address].zip(a)]}
```

Comment: `salutations.zip(first_names, last_names, addresses).map...` ? :)

Comment: @fl00r Hi. That works as well, but I respected symmetry here.

Comment: Thanks @sawa, appreciate the help. The only solution I could come up with on my own is now listed in the question as well. Any idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: It is because there is no method like `salutations(array_index)`. If you want to get the element of `saluations` at index `array_index`, then you need to do `salutations[array_index]` as in Zippie's answer.

Comment: I'm still getting an error actually: "`array_to_hash': undefined local variable or method `array_index' for main:Object (NameError)".           Any insight as to why this is?

Comment: Because that variable is defined outside of the method definition, and is not accessible from the method definition.

Comment: Ok, I assume that's why I keep getting that error message for hash[salutation] etc and array_of_hashes?

Comment: Are you satisfied with answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
5.times.map do |x|
  {    
   salutation: salutations[x],
   first_name: first_names[x],
   last_name: last_names[x],
   address: addresses[x]
  }
end
```

or if you're not sure if it's going to be only five items in each array, substitute `5.times` with e.g. `salutations.length.times`.

Comment: Thanks Zippie. In this case is the x going to stand for the index in the arrays salutations, first_names, last_names, and addresses?

Comment: Yes, the x is the index

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [:salutations, :first_names, :last_names, :addresses]
data = [ salutations,  first_names,  last_names,  addresses].transpose

data.map!{|person|  Hash[keys.zip(person)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass you have to pass `array_index` in as a parameter because you can't access variables **outside** of the method.